# What is the opposite of oninput in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

In my `vue` project I have created component for 2FA fields, it consists 6 inputs, and they look like this:

```html
<input
      class="input-two-fa"
      :id="`n5`" type="number"
      v-model="i5"
      :disabled="disabled"
      min="0"
      max="9"
      autocomplete="off"
      autofocus
      oninput="this.nextElementSibling.focus()"
    >
```

As you can see, there such line of code:

```html
oninput="this.nextElementSibling.focus()"
```

It focuses next input, when user provides value. What I need, is to implement such functionality that would focus on previous inout if user removes value (missclick, for example).

Is there any built-in (like `oninput="this.nextElementSibling.focus()"`) functionality or I have to create my own?

Basically, in pseudocode, I need not `oninput`, but `onoutpunt`. Event listener, for deleting characters from input.

Comment: `oninput` fires for any editing. If you want to do something conditional on the result of the editing, you need to use an `if` statement.

Comment: it's in fact the same event handler. `oninput="if (this.value == '') { this.previousElementSibling.focus() } else { this.nextElementSibling.focus() }"`